# mySQL "With Recursive" query fails using UPDATE (error #1241)

Tags: mysql, recursive-query

I have a recursive query that **works perfectly**. Here it is:

```
WITH RECURSIVE mgmt_levels AS ( SELECT jobholder_uid, positionmgr_uid, position_level FROM positions WHERE positionmgr_uid = 'foo.bar@company.com'
UNION ALL
SELECT p.jobholder_uid, p.positionmgr_uid, p.position_level FROM positions p INNER JOIN mgmt_levels ml ON ml.jobholder_uid = p.positionmgr_uid )
SELECT jobholder_uid, positionmgr_uid, position_level
FROM mgmt_levels ml;
```

However, if I now want to perform an 'UPDATE' to the output from the original (successful) query, I get an error (#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)). I looked up this error but I don't see where I have made the error. What am I missing here? Any help/direction appreciated. Here is my UPDATE code ...

```
UPDATE positions SET bu_div = 'Customer Services' WHERE jobholder_uid IN
(
WITH RECURSIVE mgmt_levels AS ( SELECT jobholder_uid, positionmgr_uid, position_level, bu_div FROM positions WHERE positionmgr_uid = 'foo.bar@company.com'
UNION ALL
SELECT p.jobholder_uid, p.positionmgr_uid, p.position_level, p.bu_div FROM positions p INNER JOIN mgmt_levels ml ON ml.jobholder_uid = p.positionmgr_uid )
SELECT jobholder_uid, positionmgr_uid, position_level, bu_div
FROM mgmt_levels ml
);
```

Comment: `WHERE jobholder_uid IN ( ... SELECT jobholder_uid, positionmgr_uid, position_level, bu_div ...)` - really?

Comment: @Akina I picked this approach up from another SO post so if it is not the right way to go about this, could you provide some direction?

Comment: I have derived value from Stack Overflow for many years but I've never asked a question until now. Getting a response of "Really?" doesn't help when - clearly - I am not understanding something (or I wouldn't have asked in the first place). With my history of reviewing Stack Overflow posts for advice and suggestions on myriad coding complexities (with great thanks to the community) I was expecting a little more understanding that the "ask" is coming from someone struggling to learn. A response of "Really?" doesn't help with understanding. Would appreciate some direction here. Thank you.

Comment: You want to find single value in the output rows, where each row contains 4 columns. It is obvious that single value cannot store 4 columns.

Comment: That helps. Thank you! While it is "obvious" to you (and makes sense) I was not understanding how the UPDATE and SELECT were interacting. I will read up on this and continue my attempts to make this work. I appreciate the direction.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is posted below for anyone trying to do a recursive UPDATE. My mistake was too many columns in the final SELECT statement. This works:

```
UPDATE positions SET bu_div = 'Customer Services' WHERE jobholder_uid IN
(
WITH RECURSIVE mgmt_levels AS ( SELECT jobholder_uid, positionmgr_uid, position_level, bu_div FROM positions WHERE positionmgr_uid = 'fname.lname@examplecompany.com'
UNION ALL
SELECT p.jobholder_uid, p.positionmgr_uid, p.position_level, p.bu_div FROM positions p INNER JOIN mgmt_levels ml ON ml.jobholder_uid = p.positionmgr_uid )
SELECT jobholder_uid
FROM mgmt_levels ml
);
```